# Command still taking from database even though "candies" is less than "stealAmt"

Tags: database, discord, discord.js

So I'm a little new to this but I think this should be working, I feel like I'm missing something so simple but I'm to close to it to realize.

Everytime I run the command it takes from the user regardless if they have a negative balance but if I reverse it and have Candies > steamAmt it works and runs the command.

Any help would be appreciated.

````
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const profileModel = require("../models/profileSchema");
const parseMilliseconds = require("parse-ms-2");

module.exports = {
  cooldown: 10,
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("steal")
    .setDescription("steals candies from a user")
    .addUserOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("user")
        .setDescription("The user you want to steal from")
        .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addIntegerOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("amount")
        .setDescription("The amount you want to steal")
        .setRequired(true)
        .setMinValue(1)
        .setMaxValue(2)
    ),
  async execute(interaction, profileData) {
    const recieveUser = interaction.options.getUser("user");
    const stealAmt = interaction.options.getInteger("amount");

    try {
      await interaction.deferReply();

      const commandName = `Steal`;
      const userId = interaction.user.id;

      let cooldown = await Cooldown.findOne({ userId, commandName });

      if (cooldown && Date.now() < cooldown.endsAt) {
        const { default: prettyMs } = await import(`pretty-ms`);

        await interaction.editReply(
          `You are on cooldown, come back after ${prettyMs(
            cooldown.endsAt - Date.now()
          )}`
        );
        return;
      }

      if (!cooldown) {
        cooldown = new Cooldown({ userId, commandName });
      }
      const { Candies } = profileData;

      if (Candies < stealAmt) {
        return await interaction.editReply(
          `They do not have ${stealAmt} candies in their bag!`
        );
      }

      const recieveUserData = await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          userId: recieveUser.id,
        },
        {
          $inc: {
            Candies: -stealAmt,
          },
        }
      );

      if (!recieveUserData) {
        return await interaction.editReply(
          `<@${recieveUser.id}> doesn't have a bag!`
        );
      }

      await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          userId: interaction.user.id,
        },
        {
          $inc: {
            Candies: +stealAmt,
          },
        }
      );
      cooldown.endsAt = Date.now() + 0;

      await Promise.all([cooldown.save(), profileData.save()]);

      interaction.editReply(
        `You have stolen ${stealAmt} candies from <@${recieveUser.id}>`
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error handing /steal ${error}`);
    }
  },
}; ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Put the `return` statement after the `interaction.editReply` method.